# addressing color of a link within a li within a div

Tags: css

Hello I have the following html:

```
      <div id="tbs_horizontal_menus" class="tbs_horizontal_menus">
        <ul id="tbs_menu" class="tbs_menu">
          <li> <!-- menu 0 start //-->
                    <a href="/index.php?p=Home&ms=m0&l=en&">
                      <span class="tbs_menu_text">Home</span>
                    </a>
          </li> <!-- menu 0 end //-->
          <li> <!-- menu 1 start //-->
                    <a href="/index.php?p=Biography&ms=m1&l=en&">
                      <span class="tbs_menu_text">Biography</span>
                    </a>
          </li> <!-- menu 1 end //-->
          <li> <!-- menu 2 start //-->
                    <a href="/index.php?p=Clients&ms=m2&l=en&">
                      <span class="tbs_menu_text">Clients</span>
                    </a>
          </li> <!-- menu 2 end //-->
          <li> <!-- menu 3 start //-->
                    <a href="/index.php?p=Gallery&ms=m3&l=en&">
                      <span class="tbs_menu_text">Gallery</span>
                    </a>
          </li> <!-- menu 3 end //-->
          <li class="nav_menu_loc"> <!-- menu 5 start //-->
                    <a class="nav_menu_loc" href="/index.php?p=Contacts&ms=m5&l=en&">
                      <span class="tbs_menu_text">Contacts</span>
                    </a>
          </li> <!-- menu 5 end //-->
        </ul>
      </div >
```

I am trying to change the color of the word "Contacts" which is a link but I am obviously doing something wrong.

I've tried this:

```
li.nav_menu_loc a.nav_menu_loc {
    color: red;
}
```

as well as:

```
#tbs_menu li.nav_menu_loc a {
     color: red;
}
```

and other combinations.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Both work for me http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/N4FmH/ (first example). Do you have more CSS that may be overriding this?

Comment: I do have other definitions. In particular the one causing my headache is: `.tbs_menu li .tbs_menu_text { color: blue; }` - how can I define just my nav_menu_loc without being affected by my tbs_menu_text class?

Comment: I guess i have to do `li.nav_menu_loc .nav_menu_loc .tbs_menu_text` is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

You may have other CSS style that overwrites your desired element styling, you can use :

```
li.nav_menu_loc a.nav_menu_loc {
    color: red !important;
}
```

Or you can add an id to the `a` element and trace element in CSS by id:

example:

```
a#my_id { color : red; }
```